# What is the volume of an arbitrary intersection of a cube and a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, volume

I need to find the volume of an arbitrary intersection of a cube and a cylinder. the sides of the cube ($a$) will always be less than the diameter of the cylinder, such that a cube can fit fully inside the cylinder. Anyone have any idea how to find the volume of the intersection with the cube at an arbitrary position?

I found [this case](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalWedge.html) which seems to be the right shape for the intersection but the solution stipulates that $a>r$ which will never be true in my case.

It is also possible to assume that the intersection is close to a [wedge](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wedge.html) (ie $a<<r$) but this will not always be the case.

Note: You can assume the cylinder is infinite.

Comment: Is it really worth the hassle to come up with analytic solutions instead a numerical solution?

Comment: It has become necessary. I have been using a numerical solution to simulate ~900. I now need to simulate ~4 million cases.

Comment: Any restrictions on the rotational degrees of freedom of the cube?

Comment: Preferably no, but a "simple" case of when the cube is parallel to the cylinder would also be helpful.

Comment: *the sides of the cube will always be less than the diameter of the cylinder, such that a cube can fit fully inside the cylinder* - This sentence is wrong. Perhaps you meant diagonals ?

Comment: [Similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617071), to draw inspiration from.

Answer (score 1):

Citing from an answer to the sub case [area of intersection of circle and square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801259/area-of-intersection-of-circle-and-square):

> The formula will be a mess, no matter how you look at it. There will
>   be a lot of cases, period.

I would strongly advise to apply numerical methods here. Or maybe calculating some points in your configuration space (which might be the set of all $(a/r, x, y, \alpha, \beta))$ and then resort to approximation.